# case statement in select in jpql

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have tried the following but not working.

```
String mainQuerySt = "select o.progressStatus, "
+ " CASE WHEN o.assigneeEmployee IS NOT NULL THEN o.assigneeEmployee.fullNameSt ELSE '' END as assignee "
+ " from Tt o"

em.createQuery(mainQuerySt).getResultList();
```

What is wrong with this? Actually, I want to show assigneeEmployee full name if it is not null and otherwise an empty string.

I am using EclipseLink v2.1 as JPA

Thanks in advnace.

[EclipseLink Tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#WHERE_Clause)

Comment: Explain 'not working'. Do you get an error?

Comment: Show the error please, the query seems fine to me

Comment: No error but not getting the result. But if I omit the case statement, it is returning result. Seems odd to me.

Comment: I do not see anything in the JPQL language reference that suggests it supports CASE statements. Maybe what you want is a native query.

Comment: This works for me partialy with EclipseLink V2.3 except ELSE ' ' returns NULL instead of blank.

Comment: @AlanHay Of course JPQL accepts CASE statements, has for some time. http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/jpql.html#CASE_expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using o.assigneeEmployee IS NOT NULL, and I assume o.assigneeEmployee is a relationship.  Using dot notation forces an inner join, which then will filter out nulls.  Try

```
String mainQuerySt = "select o.progressStatus, "
+ " CASE WHEN assigneeEmployee IS NOT NULL THEN assigneeEmployee.fullNameSt ELSE '' END as assignee "
+ " from Tt o left outer join o.assigneeEmployee assigneeEmployee"
```

If it does not return the results expected, then you will need to turn on SQL logging to see the SQL produced, and show the results you do expect.